# Topological quantum field theory does predict "macroscopic objects are like elementary particles"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, action

I have the topological quantum field theory with action

$$S = \int_\Sigma d^D\sigma \sqrt{\det(G)},\qquad G_{ij} = <\partial_ix,\partial_jx>.\tag{1}$$

Here, $\Sigma$ is a $d$-dimensional hypersurface in a $D$-dimensional spacetime parametrized by the $D$-dimensional vector $x=x(\sigma_1,\dots\sigma_d)$. The action is clearly invariant on changes of the metric defined for hypersurface.

My questions are:

- What topological invariants does this field theory compute?
- Supposing I have additional fermionic action on $\Sigma$, i.e.

$$S_f=\int_\Sigma d^D\sigma (-i\psi^\dagger \gamma_\mu \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \sigma_i} \partial_i\psi)\tag{2}$$

with latin indices denoting hypersurface coordinates and Greek indices denoting ambient spacetime coordinates. The hypersurface $\Sigma$ might be a macroscopic objects that can be seen in everyday life, e.g. a human being. If I would do perturbative expension to Loop order, will I obtain an amplitude that $\Sigma$ and anti-$\Sigma$ is created from a sufficiently large energy? I would say yes; such theories can describe any topology of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): The actions (1) & (2) are not [TQFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory)s in the standard sense.

Comment: (1) is just the Nambu-Goto action for bosonic string. On what does $\gamma^{\mu}$ act in (2)? It bears spacetime index, but there are no spacetime spinors in the action, as far as I understand.